# Анимация стилей при помощи JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как правильно прописать анимацию для блока, которая выполнялась бы по нажатию на кнопку или ссылку (лучше просто слово которое является ссылкой). У меня есть скрипт который по селектору при наведении мыши изменяет нужные блоки.

jquery.easing.1.3.js - это библиотека

Это непосредственно сам скрипт:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){

//When mouse rolls over
$("#ramka").mouseover(function(){
$(this).stop().animate({width:'440px', height:'200px', top:'40px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
});

//When mouse is removed
$("#ramka").mouseout(function(){
$(this).stop().animate({width:'240px', height:'100px', top:'20px'},{queue:false, duration:3000, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
});

});
```

`$("#ramka").mouseover(function()` - я так понимаю тут надо указать онклик или может все это функциями сделать и потом онклик(название функции)? Только вот как правильно все это написать, я пока не понял.

Параллельно вопрос, кто знает, как бы плавный перезд БГ блока сделать при помощи JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#knopka').toggle(function(){
    $('#block').stop().animate({width:'440px', height:'200px', top:'40px'}, 600, 'easeOutBounce')
}, function(){
    $('#block').stop().animate({width:'240px', height:'100px', top:'20px'}, 3000, 'easeOutBounce')
});
```

Угадал мысли?

Comment: т.е. тут получается по нажатию на ссылку с ид кнопка блок с ид блок будет менять свои размеры (первая функция) а вторая просто его уменьшает по повторному нажатию?

Comment: Ваш скрипт работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить изменение св-ва display:none; хочу сделать так чтобы при нажатии одна кнопка пропадала, другая появлялась? Соответственно первая раскрывает, вторая сворачивает блок.

Comment: написал свой вариант скрипта:
$('#kn').click(function(){
    $('#bl').stop().animate({width:'440px', height:'200px'}, 600, 'easeOutBounce');
 $('#kn').hide("slow");
 $('#kn1').show("slow");
}); 
$('#kn1').click(function(){
    $('#bl').stop().animate({width:'240px', height:'100px'}, 3000, 'easeOutBounce');
 $('#kn1').hide("slow");
 $('#kn').show("slow");
}); 
может посоветуете как его оптимизировать?)

Comment: Да, вроде, никак. Разве что написать отдельную функцию для связывания элементов... но это уже на бред похоже. =)

Answer (score 1):

От себя я бы дал совет оценить JS скрипты этой системы [SL SYSTEM](http://sl-cms.com/)

Там масса решений на JS которыее сразу покажутся немыслимы)))

Comment: спс, сейчас погляжу)

Comment: От меня тоже спс.